# How to get a grand total of distinct cells based on T-sql count output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm in the process of trying to get the count from an output of a T-SQL query.

Here's the sample table information...

```
 ------------------------------------------------------
| order_no    |    company  | destination  |  date    |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     100     | Burger King | Los Angeles  | 20140305 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     101     | Burger King | Phoenix      | 20140312 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     102     | Burger King | Los Angeles  | 20140322 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     103     |  McDonalds  | Las Vegas    | 20140315 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     104     |  McDonalds  | Las Vegas    | 20140324 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     105     |  McDonalds  | Las Vegas    | 20140305 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     106     |  McDonalds  | Las Vegas    | 20140311 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     107     | Burger King | San Diego    | 20140317 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     108     | Burger King | Los Angeles  | 20140305 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     109     | Burger King | Phoenix      | 20140311 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     110     | Burger King | San Diego    | 20140313 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     111     | Burger King | Los Angeles  | 20140319 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
|     112     | Burger King | San Diego    | 20140304 |
|-------------|-------------|--------------|----------|
```

Based on this information, I then run the following query.

```
SELECT company, COUNT(destination) as company_destination, destination 
from dbo.burger_orders 
WHERE (date >= 20140301 AND date <= 20140331) 
group by company, destination
```

So the result is below.  This is exactly what I want for one bit of information I need.  However, I need an additional stat from this result below.  I need to get a count of every destination noted below.

```
  Company        Company Orders            Destination
    Burger King           4                  Los Angeles
    Burger King           3                  San Diego
    Burger King           2                  Phoenix
    McDonald's            4                  Las Vegas
```

***DESIRED OUTPUT***
***So What I need to show is the 'Destination' column grand total which is 4 based on each city in the column above.***

I'm stumped as to how to approach this as you note below I haven't been too successful partially because I have never been in this scenario before.

What I've tried

```
SELECT company, COUNT(destination) as company_destination, 
COUNT(DISTINCT destination) 
from dbo.burger_orders 
WHERE (date >= 20140301 AND date <= 20140331) 
group by company, destination
```

AND

```
SELECT company, COUNT(destination) as company_destination, 
SUM(COUNT(DISTINCT destination)) from dbo.burger_orders 
WHERE (date >= 20140301 AND date <= 20140331) 
group by company, destination
```

The first gets just turns the destination column into a 1 in every cell in the destination column.  I get that.  However I need the grand total from this.  I tried slapping a SUM in front of the COUNT in the second example and got the following error.

Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquesry.

Am I even on the right path to get the correct result?

Comment: Can you modify your question to include your desired output?  What does "a 'Destination' grand total of 4 based on each city" mean?

Comment: @gordonlinoff The second question - That is based on the output 'table' above.  The 'destination' column has cities listed.  I need to get a total of every city listed.

Comment: @TechieJoe - You could have added a column "NumOfCities" to the last table where each row = 4, right ?

Comment: @TechieJoe . . . Do you want to add a new column or a new row?  Is the number "4" derived from the count of the different cities?

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I'd just prefer to put it in a new Gridview as it's for reporting purposes.  It's better just to make things cleaner and more organized.

Comment: Thanks for the Answers everyone.  I'm going through the links on how to put the answers below together as well as seeing which answer works for what I need.  I first want to learn the theory behind it before I plug it into my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you ?

```
SELECT company, 
COUNT(destination) as company_destination, 
destination,
count(destination) over() as TotalCities 
from dbo.burger_orders 
WHERE (date >= 20140301 AND date <= 20140331) 
group by company, destination
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [analytic functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

Something [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4eee9/25):

```
SELECT company, company_orders, COUNT(destination) OVER () AS dest_count 
FROM (
    SELECT company, COUNT(destination) as company_orders, destination 
    FROM burger_orders 
    WHERE (date >= 20140301 AND date <= 20140331) 
    GROUP BY company, destination
) x
GROUP BY company, company_orders, destination;
```

Comment: I don't see any difference between my query and yours, other than yours is longer. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I tested yours, they both work. Asker can choose whichever one he prefers I guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to add another column that is the total number of rows in the result set, then you can use a window function:

```
SELECT company, COUNT(destination) as company_destination, destination,
       count(*) over () as NumCompanyDestinations
from dbo.burger_orders 
WHERE (date >= 20140301 AND date <= 20140331) 
group by company, destination;
```

This will add a new column to the result set that has `4` on every row.